# Reuse Bitbucket instance when developing multiple plugins

Tags: bitbucket-server, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am looking into bitbucket server plugin development and using atlas on mac. From what I understand in the tutorials, you write your code and run `atlas-run` to execute - but this downloads the entire bitbucket application.

Is there a way to download this implementation once and share among plugins for development? Or to tell `atlas` the location of the shared instance?

Comment: what do you want to share? the git data? the bitbucket running instance? If you are concerned about the download process, I think it relies on maven and the same BB version won't be downloaded twice.

Comment: Yeah, the download process. It sticks everything into `target` of the current project

Comment: In addition its really badly documented - or documentation partial/broken.

Comment: yeah, Atlassian's documentation isn't perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment the download process relies on maven repository `find  ~/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/ -name \*.war` returns 
`~/.m2/repository/com/atlassian//bitbucket/server/bitbucket-webapp/5.5.2/bitbucket-webapp-5.5.2.war`

So as long as you use the same maven repo and use the same BB version it will reuse the existing `war` file from the `maven` repo

Comment: I created 2 different plugin projects, ran `atlas-run` (installed from homebrew on mac) and even though for the first plugin then entire 2GB+ was downloaded, then same happened for the second.

Comment: and if you run `atlas-run` again, does it download again?